# Send msg over LAN - wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, lan

I'm trying to send a message to one of the neighbors by connecting to his wireless router (*Open - No security*) and notice him to "Put a password on the router!".

I find his IP `192.168.1.2` and mine is `192.168.1.5` ( for now ), I can ping him, default gateway ip is `192.168.1.1`.

I'm running win XP which I can use `msg 192.168.1.2 hi guy!` command but it says:
`192.168.1.2 does not exist or is disconnected`

I also tried `net send` with no success `net send 192.168.1.2 hi guy!`:

```
An error occurred while sending a message to 192.168.1.2.
The message alias could not be found on the network.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2273.
```

Also `net view` command just displays me on the network.

helps needed.

Comment: Why do you think he needs to put a password on his WiFi?  Perhaps he/she intentionally has it open?

Comment: @ernie, well in my country charging prices are high. then i don't think so. and i think it's more considerable that he don't know basic things about wireless router well.

Comment: or walk across the road and have a conversation with him...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *your neighbour might not even be using Windows*. Even if it is the case, `net send` has been deprecated years ago. It is not present on Windows Vista and Seven (and as @ernie points out on a comment, even on XP it is [present but disabled by default](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839018) since SP2). `msg` can be used to send messages in a similar way to `net send`, but it is not intended as a replacement for it:

> The msg command is intended to be used as a messaging system to
>   terminal server users, not necessarily between two Windows 7
>   computers, for example.

([source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/msg-command.htm))

Unlike `net send`, `msg` doesn't need a running service, but it has some caveats:

- You can't send MSG from Vista/7 machines to XP machines and vice-versa.
- The receiving machine should have the origin user as admin on the receiving machine. If not, then a message "**[user] does not exist or is disconnected**" is displayed.
- Firewall settings, domain rules and admin policies might interfere with the service.

[Source](http://idevar.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/onde-esta-o-net-send-no-windows-7-e-no-windows-vista/) (in Portuguese)

Comment: The Messenger service has also been disabled by default since XP SP2, not to mention they may be a non-Windows user.

Comment: @ernie By "messenger service" you mean `net send`, right? IIRC, it has been disabled by default since XP. Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to add. Also, they can be using a non-MS OS as you said. I'm adding both points to my answer.

Comment: Here's a source for disabling of the Messenger service: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839018

Answer (score 0):

"Create a basic webpage that states your message. Change router settings to redirect all requests to this page." This is what I would say if I were the kind of person to do this.

Comment: All he/she has stated in their question is that the wifi is accessible, not that the router is unprotected . . .

Comment: @ernie Well, says the router is "open, no security", it might either mean no wifi password is asked upon connection, or the router admin panel is openly accessible. In the second case, this answer is the most effective possible.

Comment: If it's the second and you're not averse to messing with the routers settings, I think changing the SSID to something would be easier and make more sense, i.e. `currentSSID` to `currentSSID needspassword`  Not that I think that's a good idea.